# variant of the stable roommates problem

Tags: algorithms, matching

The Stable Roommates Problem matches 2n participants into n sets of roommates based off of each participant's list of preferences. I was wondering if there was a variant of this problem where the number of roommates is different. For example, matching 10n participants into n sets. Thanks for the help.

Edit: The Hospital Resident problem is also similar to this. Each hospital can take a certain number of residents. The problem is the residents list their preferences by hospital instead of other residents.

Comment: I'm not sure a stable assignment (properly defined) exists in this setting – have you considered that?

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing if there isn't a solution.